# How to prevent activity from destroying in android app?

Tags: android, android-activity

I use next code to share some text using available clients:

```
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Here's some text for Twitter.");
    share.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share this via"));
```

It works (opens twitter client, as sample), but when I was close that app, I was find that my app also closed. But I need my app still to be active. What I need to do for this?

Answer (score 3):

[Your app will be in the background, onResume and onPause will both be called](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle), provided that the OS have enough memory to keep the new app and all the old apps.

- If you have a long running process that you need while the user not looking at it, use a service.
- If you need the user to return the app in the same state, [you need to do the work in onResume and onPause to save the state information and initialize your UI again](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) when the user comes back. If you are really worried that it can get killed (well, it shouldn't lose the bundle I think), you can store them in SharePreferences for your app.
- If you want to know when the app returns from that specific share intent, use startActivityForResult

Comment: Thank for hint about where I must save and restore app state. But main problem is that the my app is not active when I close another app, and I need to run it by hands. I can't understand how to reactivate my app after other app, that activated from my, is closed.

Comment: Your app will open if the user press back button. especially if you do startActivityForResult, it will always return to your activity with the correct information.

Comment: It not exact as you say. When the code from first post executed, the "Select app" dialog appears. Next, I choose the twitter client, it runs, and my app seems at background. Next, I push the "Tweet" button, and at this moment my app disappears. Next, I push the "Back" harware button, and twitter client exits,

Comment: and I can see standard device screen (desktop). Something wrong here, but I can't understand what, and why it happens.

Comment: Ah, I see. This is a classic example of application does not respecting Android lifecycle (shame on Twitter). What you can do is use a service to monitor if the twitter client have exited. This will be much more involved in which you have to check running applications periodically.

Comment: I try the standard app "Send via SMS/MMS" - its behavior is the same

Comment: Main problem is that the twitter client is not a main target of my app, and I can't monitor every possible app

Comment: You could use a service to do the monitoring, but that'd be hard and not elegant.