# How to be sure the Activity will not be "destroyed" after starting other Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I am making app that opens message app (goSMS pro in my case). After closing message app, my app is also closed and I go to the launcher/home.
How to prevent destroying my Activity?

Comment: look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12962567/3326331)

Comment: You can always [SaveState](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState) and then [RestoreState](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#RestoreState)

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid deliberately destroying your activity, but you cannot prevent your activity from being destroyed.  You should always assume that it will be destroyed, and test how it behaves when it is destroyed by turning on the "don't keep activities" developer option.

Answer (score 0):

Don't finish your Activity, and the previous Activity will be added to the stack. I also suggest that you add onActivityResults(int, int, Intent) method in this situation.